# Deploy contract on Hyperledger Besu zero fees network

Tags: ethers.js, besu, hyperledger

I have a Hyperledger Besu blockchain working on my VM with 4 nodes, built with [Qorum Quickstart](https://besu.hyperledger.org/stable/private-networks/tutorials/quickstart), using [NPX](https://besu.hyperledger.org/stable/private-networks/tutorials/quickstart). This blockchain is configured for 0 fees. ([doc](https://besu.hyperledger.org/23.4.0/private-networks/how-to/configure/free-gas))
I can develop, build, deploy, use my contract on Remix, but when i want to deploy the same smart contract on Visual Studio Code i have some mistakes with web3.js and ethers.js. On this post i just explain ethers.js issue but i can create another post for web3.js.

- Ubuntu : 22.04.1 LTS
- Docker : 20.10.12
- Besu : image: hyperledger/besu:${BESU_VERSION:-latest}
- solc : 0.8.21

This is my genesis file content :

```
{
    "config" : {
      "chainId" : 1337,
      "homesteadBlock": 0,
      "eip150Block": 0,
      "eip155Block": 0,
      "eip158Block": 0,
      "byzantiumBlock": 0,
      "constantinoplefixblock" : 0,
      "qbft": {
        "epochlength": 30000,
        "blockperiodseconds": 5,
        "requesttimeoutseconds": 10
      }
    },
    "nonce" : "0x0",
    "timestamp" : "0x58ee40ba",
    "gasLimit" : "0x1fffffffffffff",
    "difficulty" : "0x1",
    "number": "0x0",
    "gasUsed": "0x0",
(...)
```

This is my contract :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract Test {
    function retriveString() public pure returns (string memory) {
        return "string returned";
    }
}
```

This is my JS code for deploy the smart contract :

```
// Import the ethers.js library
const { ethers, JsonRpcProvider, ContractFactory } = require("ethers");
const fs = require("fs");
const solFile = fs.readFileSync("../Test.sol", "utf8");
const solc = require("solc");

// 11/09/23 : back from 0 with ethers.js

const provider = new JsonRpcProvider("http://localhost:8545");
const privateKey =
  "0x0ba970ff5e9b9c4ce2435fdf94a998af0b5892c4f6f7cb9c3fcb0772ae98ab54";
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);

async function buildContract() {
  const input = {
    language: "Solidity",
    sources: {
      "Test.sol": {
        content: solFile,
      },
    },
    settings: {
      outputSelection: {
        "*": {
          "*": ["*"],
        },
      },
    },
  };
  const output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));
  const bytecode = output.contracts["Test.sol"]["Test"].evm.bytecode.object;
  const abi = output.contracts["Test.sol"]["Test"].abi;
  console.log('output => ' ,output)
  console.log('bytecode => ' ,bytecode)
  console.log('abi => ' ,abi)

  const factory3 = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, bytecode, wallet);
  const nonce = await provider.getTransactionCount(wallet)
  const contractDeployed = await factory3.deploy({
    gasLimit: "0x4e85c",
    gasPrice: "0x0",
    nonce: nonce
  });

  // ERROR IF I USE THE LINE BELLOW
  // await contractDeployed.waitForDeployment();
  // -----------------------

  console.log("contractDeployed ==> ", contractDeployed);

  const contractDeployedAddress = await contractDeployed.getAddress();
  console.log("contractDeployedAddress ==> ", contractDeployedAddress);

  const myContract = new ethers.Contract(
    contractDeployedAddress,
    abi,
    wallet
  );
  
  const deployedTx = contractDeployed.deploymentTransaction()
  console.log('deployedTx ==> ' ,deployedTx)

  myContract['retriveString'].staticCall().then(result => {
    console.log('result in staticCall ==> ' ,result)
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log("error ==> " ,error)
  })

}

buildContract();
```

In case where i don't use the line `await contractDeployed.waitForDeployment()` i can display these console.log, and work with "contractDeployed" but i have error with my smart contract function :

output :

```
output =>  {
  contracts: { 'Test.sol': { Test: [Object] } },
  sources: { 'Test.sol': { id: 0 } }
}
```

abi :

```
[
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: 'retriveString',
    outputs: [ [Object] ],
    stateMutability: 'pure',
    type: 'function'
  }
]
```

bytecode :

```
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
```

contractDeployed :

```
BaseContract {
  target: '0xae4C40737AEC8D59721d90efCF8c95ADCB348A3D',
  interface: Interface {
    fragments: [ [FunctionFragment] ],
    deploy: ConstructorFragment {
      type: 'constructor',
      inputs: [],
      payable: false,
      gas: null
    },
    fallback: null,
    receive: false
  },
  runner: Wallet {
    provider: JsonRpcProvider {},
    address: '0xd48ab4450681d37CbfbDcf21e0b1eE9405045A9F'
  },
  filters: {},
  fallback: null,
  [Symbol(_ethersInternal_contract)]: {}
}
```

contractDeployedAddress : 0xae4C40737AEC8D59721d90efCF8c95ADCB348A3D

deployedTx :

```
ContractTransactionResponse {
  provider: JsonRpcProvider {},
  blockNumber: null,
  blockHash: null,
  index: undefined,
  hash: '0xb202de7c28e98e142a4f9e636a36b737dcfc91df3fb33d75629e525386779bc2',
  type: 0,
  to: null,
  from: '0xd48ab4450681d37CbfbDcf21e0b1eE9405045A9F',
  nonce: 352,
  gasLimit: 321628n,
  gasPrice: 0n,
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: null,
  maxFeePerGas: null,
  data: '0x608060405234801561000f575f80fd5b506101688061001d5f395ff3fe608060405234801561000f575f80fd5b5060043610610029575f3560e01c806319ea3c781461002d575b5f80fd5b61003561004b565b6040516100429190610112565b60405180910390f35b60606040518060400160405280600f81526020017f737472696e672072657475726e65640000000000000000000000000000000000815250905090565b5f81519050919050565b5f82825260208201905092915050565b5f5b838110156100bf5780820151818401526020810190506100a4565b5f8484015250505050565b5f601f19601f8301169050919050565b5f6100e482610088565b6100ee8185610092565b93506100fe8185602086016100a2565b610107816100ca565b840191505092915050565b5f6020820190508181035f83015261012a81846100da565b90509291505056fea26469706673582212203f6d93c42f307337aa85385803ee2204170f4e2f9a0996c6e4e505037f51708064736f6c63430008150033',
  value: 0n,
  chainId: 1337n,
  signature: Signature { r: "0xf6c49a0fb65d2570856a3046b1ef943f13d6e5cb271dfc1e5c3957f70350ddf4", s: "0x10a39114359a0bd86994381f0b1f6cd2765eb7cbf1d2b45426f9cce82fc7292d", yParity: 1, networkV: 2710 },
  accessList: null
}
```

error (in myContract staticCall) :

```
Error: could not decode result data (value="0x", info={ "method": "retriveString", "signature": "retriveString()" }, code=BAD_DATA, version=6.7.1)
    at makeError (/home/adminlogin/BESU_NETWORK/v5/contracts/EOBLOCK v2/contracts/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/utils/errors.js:125:21)
    at assert (/home/adminlogin/BESU_NETWORK/v5/contracts/EOBLOCK v2/contracts/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/utils/errors.js:142:15)
    at Interface.decodeFunctionResult (/home/adminlogin/BESU_NETWORK/v5/contracts/EOBLOCK v2/contracts/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/abi/interface.js:780:31)
    at staticCallResult (/home/adminlogin/BESU_NETWORK/v5/contracts/EOBLOCK v2/contracts/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/contract/contract.js:237:35)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async AsyncFunction.staticCall (/home/adminlogin/BESU_NETWORK/v5/contracts/EOBLOCK v2/contracts/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/contract/contract.js:202:24) {
  code: 'BAD_DATA',
  value: '0x',
  info: { method: 'retriveString', signature: 'retriveString()' }
}
```

But if i use the line `await contractDeployed.waitForDeployment()` i have this error :

```
Error: transaction execution reverted (action="sendTransaction", data=null, reason=null, invocation=null, revert=null, transaction={ "data": "", "from": "0xd48ab4450681d37CbfbDcf21e0b1eE9405045A9F", "to": null }, receipt={ "_type": "TransactionReceipt", "blockHash": "0xf0431aeffef9aa6c4054079280c018b4eab1fe118f6188b674c428bf29c3c26a", "blockNumber": 174615, "contractAddress": "0xC363580f4F9890Da64b47b5f396A170720905233", "cumulativeGasUsed": "321628", "from": "0xd48ab4450681d37CbfbDcf21e0b1eE9405045A9F", "gasPrice": "0", "gasUsed": "321628", "hash": "0xcbb51dcbd275a7fd616a351d9c8531403a06ed427b47d431d28ab7cb7c3c3d7d", "index": 0, "logs": [  ], "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "root": null, "status": 0, "to": null }
```

If anyone have ideas for these differents issues ...

Thanks !